# Getting error while assigning Source List to Destination List values in Composite Inner classes

Tags: c#, automapper

new for AutoMapper. I have a Composite class structure as below. I am trying to assign the OtherInnerSource List to InnerDestination List but am not able to initialize (Composite Classes properties) and getting an error.

```
class Source
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public InnerSource InnerSource { get; set; }
    public List<OtherInnerSource> OtherInnerSources { get; set; } = new List<OtherInnerSource>();
}
class InnerSource
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
class OtherInnerSource
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
class Destination
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<InnerDestination> InnerDestinations { get; set; }
}
class InnerDestination
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

my AutoMapper configuration is like this. Can you please help me with how to initialize the properties if we have Lists?

```
 public void ComplexAssignmentData()
    {
        try
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {

                cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().IncludeMembers(src => src.InnerSource, src => src.OtherInnerSources);
                cfg.CreateMap<InnerSource, Destination>(MemberList.None).ForPath(dest => dest.InnerDestinations.First().Description, opt =>
                {
                    opt.MapFrom(s => s.Description);
                    opt.Condition(c => true);
                });
                cfg.CreateMap<OtherInnerSource, Destination>(MemberList.None).ForPath(dest => dest.InnerDestinations.First().Title, opt =>
                {
                    opt.MapFrom(OtherSrc => OtherSrc.Title);
                    opt.Condition(c => true);
                });

            });

            var source = new Source
            {
                Name = "name",
                InnerSource = new InnerSource { Description = "description" },
                OtherInnerSources = { new OtherInnerSource { Title = "title" } }
            };

            config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            var destination = mapper.Map<Destination>(source);
            var plan = config.BuildExecutionPlan(typeof(Source), typeof(Destination));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Iam getting error '
Only member accesses are allowed. dest => dest.InnerDestinations.First().Description (Parameter 'destinationMember')'

while initializing from Source List(List) to Destination List(List).

How to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can call First() on the destination like that because the destination doesn't exist yet. Simply map the collection.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.InnerDestinations, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.OtherInnerSources));

cfg.CreateMap<OtherInnerSource, InnerDestination>();
```